# Unable to download Tensorflow C Language Bindings as an ExternalProject

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to include the C language bindings for Tensorflow found at https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-gpu-linux-x86_64-2.5.0.tar.gz in my CMake Project. Unfortunately, it seems as thought nothing is being downloaded, as the TENSORFLOW-prefix/src/TENSORFLOW directory is empty. I'm new to CMake and am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant source:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
include(ExternalProject)

project(tfexec)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

ExternalProject_Add(TENSORFLOW
  URL "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-gpu-linux-x86_64-2.5.0.tar.gz"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  LOG_DOWNLOAD 1
  LOG_CONFIGURE 1
  LOG_BUILD 1
  LOG_INSTALL 1
)
```

Comment: ExternalProject runs at build time, so you actually need to run your build for this to do anything. Also, don't put code before `project()` that doesn't actually have a pressing reason to be there.

Comment: If it doesn't run before build time then how do I actually link it in?

Comment: You probably want to use `FetchContent` instead, in that case. `ExternalProject` is designed to orchestrate several builds, not to pull in content to the _current_ build.

Comment: Regardless, you'll want to create SHARED IMPORTED library targets for `libtensorflow` and `libtensorflow_framework` with the required include paths, dependencies, etc.

Comment: Should it be SHARED IMPORTED or STATIC IMPORTED? I'm getting errors when trying to use SHARED IMPORTED.

Comment: Well, in my downloads I see shared libraries (`libtensorflow.so`), so it had better be shared. Feel free to open up a new question with error message details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExternalProject runs at build time, so you actually need to run your build for this to do anything. This is what I see; it seems to be working fine:

```
alex@Alex-Desktop:~/test$ cmake-3.17 -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
alex@Alex-Desktop:~/test$ cmake --build build/ -- -v
...
alex@Alex-Desktop:~/test$ tree build/TENSORFLOW-prefix/src/TENSORFLOW
build/TENSORFLOW-prefix/src/TENSORFLOW
├── LICENSE
├── THIRD_PARTY_TF_C_LICENSES
├── include
│   └── tensorflow
│       ├── c
│       │   ├── c_api.h
│       │   ├── c_api_experimental.h
│       │   ├── c_api_macros.h
│       │   ├── eager
│       │   │   ├── c_api.h
│       │   │   ├── c_api_experimental.h
│       │   │   └── dlpack.h
│       │   ├── tensor_interface.h
│       │   ├── tf_attrtype.h
│       │   ├── tf_datatype.h
│       │   ├── tf_file_statistics.h
│       │   ├── tf_status.h
│       │   ├── tf_tensor.h
│       │   └── tf_tstring.h
│       └── core
│           └── platform
│               ├── ctstring.h
│               └── ctstring_internal.h
└── lib
    ├── libtensorflow.so -> libtensorflow.so.2
    ├── libtensorflow.so.2 -> libtensorflow.so.2.5.0
    ├── libtensorflow.so.2.5.0
    ├── libtensorflow_framework.so -> libtensorflow_framework.so.2
    ├── libtensorflow_framework.so.2 -> libtensorflow_framework.so.2.5.0
    └── libtensorflow_framework.so.2.5.0

7 directories, 23 files
```